# Stop asp:Button Text from being HTML encoded

Tags: asp.net

I am maintaining an ASP.NET 3.5 application and I'd like to add some "off screen" html content within the Text property of a Button control in order to make it more accessible, e.g.

```
<asp:Button CssClass="std-text" runat="server" ID="btnChangeLocation"
            OnClick="btnChangeLocation_Click" 
            Text="Set<span class='offscreen'> Location</span>" />
```

but the Text is always HTML-encoded, how can I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

one way to do that is use a javascript replacement, for example:

```
<asp:Button CssClass="std-text" runat="server" 
       ID="btnChangeLocation" OnClick="btnChangeLocation_Click" 
       data-text="Set<span class='offscreen'> Location</span>" 
       Text="replace-text" />
```

and call a replace method on Load like:

```
$(function() {

    replaceAllTexts();
});

function replaceAllTexts() {

    // for each button
    $("input[type='button']").each(function() {

        // if the text is 'replace-text' and there is a data-text attribute
        if( $(this).text() === "replace-text" && $(this).attr("data-text") ) {
            // replace button's text
            $(this).html( $(this).attr("data-text") );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I was hoping to avoid a Javascript solution. Also, along with a couple bugs (`type='button'` -> `type='submit'` and `$(this).html` -> `$(this).val`), this doesn't work because the text in ad-hoc `data-text` attributes is HTML-encoded too!

Comment: That's no problem, use `unescape()` in javascript, and you can easily use `$("input")` only, instead of telling the selector that you only want buttons ;) - because you want to pass an HTML string, you need to set the `html()` of the element, not it's value or text.